# ASP.NET MVC url search parameter without question mark

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, url-routing

I have a route defined as:

> routes.MapRoute("AllUsers",
>   "Users/Search/{Search}", new {
>   Controller = "Users", action=
>   "Index"});

and the form as:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users/Search/", new { RouteValue = "AllUsers" }, FormMethod.Get, new { id = "searchForm" })){%>
 <input id="searchBox" name="search" type="text" />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" /><%} %>
```

Currently as expected this creates a url of
`../Users/Search/?search=searchTerm`
but what I would like is:
`../Users/Search/searchTerm`

How is this possible? I thought of using javascript, but this seems a little dirty. Is there a more streamlined way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with an HTML form. Though you can mimic the behavior with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

How about a server-side redirect?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" 
    onclick="$('form').attr('action', $('form').attr('action') + $('#searchBox').val());" />
```

Which seems a little ugly. You could also not use a form and have this:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Search" 
    onclick="window.location.href = 'search/' + $('#searchBox').val();" />
```

Outside of this, you could allow the original submit to go to the weird url, but use RedirectToAction in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                document.location.href = $("form").attr("action") + $("#searchBox").val();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("AllUsers",
"Users/Search/{id}", new { Controller = "Users", action= "Index"});
```

and the form as:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users/Search/", 
  new { RouteValue = "AllUsers" }, FormMethod.Get, new { id = "searchForm" })){%>
  <input id="searchBox" name="id" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" /><%} %>
```

Not tested, but "id" is default route value which are not creating "?name=value".